# jQuery ToggleClass - remove 2 classes and add 1 class

Tags: jquery, css

I want to do something like

HTML

```
<div class="box a b"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.box').removeClass('a b').addClass('c');
```

but is this possible using only `$.toggleClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to toggle the classes:

```
$('.box').toggleClass('a b c')
```

It will remove `a` and `b` and add `c`

And a working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.box2').toggleClass('a')
  $('.box3').toggleClass('a b')
  $('.box4').toggleClass('a b c')
});
```

```css
.a {
  color: red;
  }
.b {
  background: blue;
  }
.c {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1 a b">asd</div>
<div class="box2 a b">asd</div>
<div class="box3 a b">asd</div>
<div class="box4 a b">asd</div>
```

Comment: what if I had 2 divs: <div class="box a"></div> & <div class="box b"></div> and wanted to remove both classes a&b and add class c?

Comment: The meaning of *toggle* is add if it doesn't exists and remove if it does. If you have two different divs you can't use the toggle there, because it will add `a` to `b` and `b` to `a`.